# onShow and onHide listener in ViewPart - Java Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

I would like to trigger method when ViewPart is being hidden (hidden == it starts to be invisible) and it is being opened (opened == it starts to be visible). Something like:

```
void onHide(){removeAllListeners();}
void onShow(){refreshView();}
```

I tried to use:

```
getSite().getPage().addSelectionListener(new ISelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void selectionChanged(final IWorkbenchPart workbenchPart, final ISelection selection) {
            System.out.println("TEST");
        }});
```

but it works only when ViewPart become invisible and it is not triggered when become visible

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with selection being changed. Use an [`IPartListener2`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IPartListener2.html).

Comment: I tried to use this in this way:
getSite().getPage().addPartListener(new IPartListener2(){ ...

but when ViewPart become visible those methods are called:
partDeactivated
partActivated
partHidden
partHidden
partVisible
partVisible
partVisible
partVisible


when it becomes invisible:
partDeactivated
partActivated
partHidden
partHidden
partHidden
partHidden
partVisible
partVisible

Comment: You're notified for events about all parts. Use the passed in information to figure out if it's one of yours (such as by ID), and proceed from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IPartListener2` (or the older `IPartListener`) to listen to changes to the state of **all** parts.

```
getSite().getPage().addPartListener(new IPartListener2() ....
```

You probably want to react to the 'partHidden' and 'partVisible' methods. In these methods you will need to check that the event is for your part:

```
IViewPart myViewPart = ... your view part


@Override
public void partHidden(IWorkbenchPartReference ref) {
    IWorkbenchPart part = ref.getPart(false);

    if (part == myViewPart) {
        // Event is for your view
    }
}

@Override
public void partVisible(IWorkbenchPartReference ref) {
    IWorkbenchPart part = ref.getPart(false);

    if (part == myViewPart) {
        // Event is for your view
    }
}
```